# confusion with object datatype in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at below javascript code, when i run it it gave undefined, may i know what i am doing wrong here?

```
var fruit ={

            name:"mango",
            color:"yellow",
            nativeTo:["india","china"],
            showName:function(){ 
                return this.color + " " + this.name
            },
            foundIn: function (){
                this.nativeTo.forEach(function(country){ 
                    return ( "found in "+ country)
                })
            }    
    }       
        alert (fruit.foundIn());
```

Comment: You are doing a return into a forEach scope :P

Comment: What is the output you expect? `foundIn` doesn't return anything, so it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed `foundIn` to this:

```
  foundIn: function() {
    return this.nativeTo.map(function(country) { 
      return "found in "+ country;                                                          
    })
  }
```

That will alert with:

`found in india,found in china`

Note the use of `map` instead of `forEach` -- you can use `forEach` to iterate but then you need a variable outside of the `forEach` iteration to accumulate what you want to return (the string) and then you need to return that accumulation string.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2s3hh39/

Comment: ok i did it like this

`
  foundIn: function() {
   var tt = [];
    this.nativeTo.forEach(function(country) { 
      tt.push( "found in "+ country);                                                          
    })
    return tt;
  }
`
still this is no help i created array and pushing values into that.

Comment: @Nomad Hrm... I tried it here with http://jsfiddle.net/a2s3hh39/1/ and it seems to work.